# If they had continued... question

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar, style-manuals

"He headed the truck to the school, part way his wife decided to convince him to turn back to their house because there was fire everywere on the way to the school and she thought that they were going to die if they had continued on the way to the school" do you guys think my sentence is okey?

I want to say that:

1) The wife thought they were going to die because of the fire that there was on the way to the school
2) So he decided to convince him to turn back to their house to prevent them diying on the track to the school

Someone told me that i cant use the HAD there but i think that i can use it there.

Comment: The continuation took place in her thought before she convinced him to turn back. It's not completely wrong but he needs another *had* where she's doing the thinking. In any case, that entire section of the passage is completely redundant and should just be removed, not grammatically finessed.

Comment: lly why do you think i need another had where she's doing the thinking? I think my "had" usage there is okey, no one can answer me correctly why it's wrong, i think to have only one had there where it says "if they had continued" is okey

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: why do you think i cant use only one HAD in hat sentence? why i have to add another had to make it correct?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence isn't ok. There are some problems with the spelling and grammar, including comma splices, and some redundant redundancies that are redundant in a redundant fashion.

*He started off in his truck, but fire was spreading everywhere and  partway to the school his wife, wildly fearful, convinced him to turn back to their house.*

- He can *head to* someplace without an object (the understood object is "himself") but, if you're talking about doing something to the truck, *heading* it means "pointing in that direction" not actually traveling.
- There's a comma splice after the first phrase.
- *Partway* is a single word these days; it also usually needs some clarifying word or prepositional phrase.
- *Deciding to convince* is not an actual action taken by the wife towards the husband; it's an internal action within the wife's mind.
- You should seriously consider rewriting the passage as shorter sentences. In general, you should consider using shorter sentences until you're more comfortable with the grammar connecting English phrases.

*Had* wasn't completely wrong but that entire section of the sentence is redundant anyway and needs removal, not reworking.

Comment: Why do you think i need another HAD where she's doing the thinking? I think my "had" usage there is okey. no one can answer me correctly why it's wrong to have only one HAD. i think to have only one had there where it says "if they had continued" is okey because the thought happened in his mind and before the decision to turn back, she thought in his mind at that moment "we are going to die if we continue on the way to the school" so to narrate it as something that happened in the past ( his thinking ) i have to say that she thought that "they were going to die if they had continued on the way

Answer (score 0):

It`s the third conditional - if + past perfect, ...would + have + past participle. If you had taken the necessary precautions, nothing would have happened. In your sentence, if you want to convey the idea that the wife wanted to warn her husband about the imminent danger awaiting them, then you can say - she decided to convince her husband to turn back to their house because, she thought they would die, ( in case ) if they continued moving to the school.